# I just remembered or i have just remembered?

Tags: simple-past-vs-past-perfect, focusing-adverbs

Suppose I wrote someone an email and told him something. After a few days, it occurred to me that I forgot to tell him about other things. What is correct in this situation:

- Hi marc, I have just remembered that I forgot to tell you about other things...

or

- Hi marc, I just remembered that I forgot to tell you about other things ...

Comment: If not for that "just" in there, I'd say there's a subtle difference.  But with the "just," the two versions end up meaning the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both the sentences are correct.
The adverb *Just* is used both in the 
simple  past and present perfect and in the past perfect tense too. *Just* means 
recently when referring to time. The distinction between American and the British English is being slowly lost. Even in informal or in formal context, there is no difference.

1.`I just remembered that I forgot to tell you about other things.`

2. `I have  just remembered that I forgot to tell you about other things`

Both the sentences mean the same thing and are grammatically correct.

Comment: Thank you. i think this should be the right answer

Answer (score -2):

The *have* auxilary is not used equivalently elsewhere. So there can't be a definite answer. Some use *have* liberally, and there is no difference in meaning.

I'd argue that *have remembered X* implies *having X*, *having got X*, *having given X*, etc.

However, logically, *forgetting* precedes *remembering*, so the first variant is illogical. However, there might be a dislike for irregular participles like "forgotten" or the past perfect with "had".

Overall I'd recommend

> Hi, I need to tell you a few more things, that I just remembered.